# Harmonic function over a square with linear Neumann boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, na.numerical-analysis, harmonic-functions, laplace-equation

For a rectangle with height 1 and length 2, here is the unique numerical solution
(showing contours of the equipotential from 0, defined by the bottom, to 0.54, the numerically-calculated maximum)
to Laplace's Equation given the following mixed boundary conditions.

```
top:    0 perpendicular gradient
right:  0 perpendicular gradient
bottom: 0 tangential gradient
left:   linearly-increasing perpendicular gradient (from 0 at bottom-left to 1 at top-left)
```

[image]

Is there an analytic solution to more precisely calculate interior values? or to calculate the 0.54 maximum (maybe this can be calculated with standard constants like $\pi$)?

For background, if you have a 3D cube (or even a hypercube in higher dimensions) with any linear Neumann boundary conditions
(i.e., the normal gradient linearly increases across each face) and want to determine the unique interior function which solves
Laplace's Equation, you can basically reduce this problem to a superposition of scaled solutions of this simpler problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the meaning of your boundary conditions? Your terminology is definitely not standard for PDEs. I presume that "perprendicular gradient" means here normal derivative? Also, prescribing "zero tangential gradient" on the bottom means that the solution should be constant on the bottom, right? but this is certainly not a standard boundary condition

Comment: one way around is to notice that your boundary conditions are invariant under addition of constants, so "the" solution is also defined up to additive constants. As a consequence you can always "choose" that the constant value of your solution on the bottom should be zero, and this becomes a standard Dirichlet boundary condition.

Comment: @leomonsaingeon Yes, your assumptions and points are correct, but the lack of answers here makes me think that there are no standard function solutions which could quickly yield the 0,54 that I simulated, for example.

Comment: well, in general it is extremely difficult to get explicit, closed-form solutions for PDEs. What one can do in general is prove a rigorous convergence result for numerical methods, for your purpose this should be in any textbook in numerical analysis for elliptic PDEs. Do you have any reason not to trust your numerics?